# How to change img src directory or image file name with jquery or PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to change the image path directory or append the the image file by adding a class to the parent container.

Example: If I add a class of "large" to the parent `img` container, I would like it to either append the `img` file name or change the `img` path.

```
   src="/images/services/image.jpg" changed to src="/images/services/image-large.jpg"

   or

   src="/images/services/image.jpg" changed to src="/images/services/large/image.jpg"

   ...............................................................................



     default, no class:

        <div>
            <img src="/images/services/image.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>

     Option 1, with class:

        <div class="large-image">
            <img src="/images/services/image-large.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>


     Option 2, with class:


        <div class="large-image">
            <img src="/images/services/large/image.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
```

Comment: What is the trigger to add the class?

Comment: I would just manually add the class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example like this, using [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

```
$function() {
  var img = $(".large-image > img").each(function() { // for each img found
    var src = $(this).attr("src"); // get the src
    var path = src.substring(0,src.lastIndexOf('/')); // get the path from the src 
    var fileName = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf('/')); // and filename
    var newSrc = path+"/large"+fileName; // re-assemble   
    // or change filename:
    // var newSrc = path+"/"+fileName.replace(".jpg","-large.jpg"); // re-assemble   

    $(this).attr("src",newSrc);
  });
});
```

Comment: that would work if I only had the two images with those names, but I have many images, with many different names... example image name: tree-care-salt-lake-city.jpg.... I need something like: tree-care-salt-lake-city-large.jpg

Comment: Thanks for your help!!! so this adds large to the file name or adds large to the file path?

Comment: I tried to make a fiddle, but jsfiddle is down - you can do both - see update. I hope it works straight off since I am off to bed now

Comment: The selector is important. I simplified the code a little by using a beter selector

Answer (score 2):

you can use jquery to change the src, split it, and add your new folder

```
<div class="large-image">
     <img src="/images/services/image.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

$('.large-image > img').each(function(){
     var msrc=$(this).attr('src');
     msrc=msrc.split('/');     //images, services, image.jpg
     var lastelem = msrc.pop();  //images, services     // lastelem: image.jpg
     msrc.push('large');     //images, services, large   // lastelem: image.jpg 
     msrc.push(lastelem);    //images, services, large, image.jpg
     msrc=msrc.join('/');  //"images/services/large/image.jpg"
     $(this).attr('src', msrc);
})
```

Comment: Thanks!!! This looks like what I'm after.... would you mind creating a jsfiddle.... or explain how this works.... or maybe just show what the before and after img code would look like... thanks again!!!

Comment: I've just added some commenting that shows what's happening within the array.  Hopefully that will be helpful.  You can combine some of these commands to lessen the length of the script, but hopefully this will give you a good picture of what I'm trying

Comment: Is the $('.large-image').each( not looping over divs rather than images inside the divs?

Comment: Thanks for the help!! Looks like your method and mplungjan's method  will both get the job done.