# Image ignores structure with foundation grid in mobile

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

This is my first question here so I apologize if it's not in the right formt. I don't know why but images work perfectly fine in my desktop computer but are out of place in my mobile devices. I used chrome's mobile simulator and it works fine there too. But not in the real mobile device.

Please help :(

Comment: Are you sure you are using correct tags for the question? Please use the [How to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link for your help.

Comment: Thank you, but I cant see any relation to zurb-foundation with your question. Also, please elaborate. How its displayed and how you want? You can add images to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## There are many possibilities...

Without a look at your code, or knowing the OS for the device used it is impossible to provide a precise answer.

However, I experience similar issue with Foundation right out of the box... not sure why as well. In my application my up-loader re sizes each image and stores them in small, medium, and large folders. As a result, I need precise control on which image to load depending on device.

I came up with the system below which allows for the application of CSS to be applied according to device: This may or may not resolve you issue.

## Mobile Detect

I went [here](http://mobiledetect.net/) to get Mobile Detect which I identifies the device used.

## Code to call Mobile Detect

This calls the detect script and assigns device size to the variable: `$thisImg`

```
# mobile detect
    require_once ($level.'core/ini/mobile-detect.php'); 
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect; $deviceType = ($detect->isMobile() ? ($detect->isTablet() ? 'tablet' : 'phone') : 'computer');
    if($layoutType == 'mobile'){$thisImg = 'small';} 
    elseif($layoutType == 'tablet'){$thisImg = 'medium';} 
    elseif($layoutType == 'classic'){$thisImg = 'large';}
```

## Store Device Size

To store the device size I use a hidden input with an id of `img_sizer`

`echo '<input type="hidden" id="img_sizer" value="'.$this_img.'">';`

## jQuery

By assigning a class to the image you can now control the CSS on all the images with that assigned class according to device and can manage various image classes through jQuery.

```
$('img.respond').each(function(){
  var which_size = $('#img_sizer').val(); // my hidden input         
  if(which_size == 'small'){$(this).addClass( "text-center" );} // add center class for small
})
```

## Determining Folder Path

In my application I use the following jQuery to assign the proper folder path to the image source. The code came from Stack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962818/how-to-change-img-src-directory-or-image-file-name-with-jquery-or-php)

```
$('img.respond').each(function(){
    var which_size = $('#img_sizer').val(); // my hidden input
    var msrc=$(this).attr('src');
    msrc=msrc.split('/');     //images, services, image.jpg
    var lastelem = msrc.pop();  //images, services     // lastelem: image.jpg
    msrc.push(which_size);     //images, services, large   // lastelem: image.jpg 
   msrc.push(lastelem);    //images, services, large, image.jpg
   msrc=msrc.join('/');  //"images/services/large/image.jpg"
   $(this).attr('src', msrc);
   if(which_size == 'small'){$(this).addClass( "text-center" );} // add center class for small
 })
```

Comment: Great answer. Although what solved my problem was reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126022/foundation-image-leaves-container-in-ipad-iphone

Comment: I kind of figured the answer might not be exactly what you were looking. I'm building a `CMS` where non programmers will have their hand in the pie and needed to a simple way for them to manage which image size to load... the above system allows for the simple inclusion of a css class which they can both easily remember and assign through the WYSIWYG.